# I want to add trackbar on my media player

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a simple media player, and I want to add some general feature like a trackbar control that synchronise with video / music while they are running.

This is what I have done so far:

```
namespace Joe_Media_Player
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

#### Pause button

```
        private void pausebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPPlayState.wmppsPaused)
            {
                mediaplayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
            else
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
            }
        }
```

#### Play button

```
        private void  playbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }
```

#### Open file / browse

```
        private void BrowseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Open file //
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Multiselect = true, ValidateNames = true, Filter = "(mp3,wav,wav,mov,wmv,mpg,avi,3gp,flv|*.mp3;*.mp4;*.wav;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpg;*.avi;*.3gp;*.flv|all files|*.*" }) //HEADER
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // Kondisi mulai
                {
                    List<MediaFile> files = new List<MediaFile>(); // Membuat list baru musik/video
                    foreach (string fileName in ofd.FileNames) // Cetak file nama
                    {
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName); // New file info nama
                        files.Add(new MediaFile() { FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName), Path = fi.FullName }); // Pilih file musik/video
                    }
                    listBox1.DataSource = files; // List data file
                    listBox1.ValueMember = "Path"; // List tipe
                    listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName"; // File nama
                }
            }
        }
```

#### Minimize & maximize button

```
        private void MinBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void MaxBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        }
```

#### Rewind, stop, fastfoward, next button

```
        private void rewindbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.fastReverse();
        }

        private void prevbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(axWindowsMediaPlayer1r.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
            {
                if(listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    listBox1.Update();
                }
                else
                {
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.previous();
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex -= 1;
                    listBox1.Update();
                }
            }
            mediaplayer.Ctlcontrols.previous();
        }

        private void stopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
        }

        private void nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState== WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
            {
                if(listBox1.SelectedIndex < (listBox1.Items.Count -1))
                {
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.next();
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
                    listBox1.Update();
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    listBox1.Update();
                }
            }
        }

        private void fastfowardbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.fastForward();
        }
```

listbox1

```
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MediaFile file = listBox1.SelectedItem as MediaFile;
            if (file != null)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = file.Path;// Pilih tipe file
                mediaplayer.Ctlcontrols.play(); // Contorl mulai musik/video
            }
        }
```

volume trackbar

```
        private void volumetrackbar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rate = 100 * (bunifuSlider2.Value - 10);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = bunifuSlider2.Value;
        }

        private void volumebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume == 100)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 0;
                bunifuSlider2.Value = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 100;
                bunifuSlider2.Value = 100;
            }
        }
```

trackbar & timer (not code right now )

```
        private void trackbar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried to implement this? You need to show us your attempts at resolving the issue.

Comment: im sorry, i just need some help

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_OpenStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.openState == WMPLib.WMPOpenState.wmposMediaOpen)
        {
            trackBar1.Maximum = (int)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBar1.Value = (int)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
    }


    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = trackBar1.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't add answers with "code only". Could you explain how this solves the question? Thanks!